# DAX - problem with the RELATED() function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to DAX, and right now I'm trying to create my first serious project in Power BI. I have a premier league season database which main part of the model looks like this:
[image: abc]

The club_id column in the Clubs table is connected to both home_team_id and away_team_id columns in Matches table.

What I'm trying to do is to create a DAX measure which will print the biggest win out of all matches. The example of a format I'm trying to get is: "Liverpool 9:0 Bournemouth'.

The code that I have written looks like that:

```
HighestWin = 
VAR BiggestGD = MAXX(Matches, 
                    ABS(Matches[home_team_goals] - Matches[away_team_goals]))
VAR BiggestGDRow = 
    FILTER(Matches, 
        ABS(Matches[home_team_goals] - Matches[away_team_goals]) = BiggestGD)

VAR HomeTeam = CALCULATE(Related(Clubs[club_name]), USERELATIONSHIP(Clubs[club_id], Matches[home_team_id]))
VAR AwayTeam = CALCULATE(Related(Clubs[club_name]), USERELATIONSHIP(Clubs[club_id], Matches[away_team_id]))

VAR ResultList = CONCATENATEX(BiggestGDRow,
                            HomeTeam  & " " & [home_team_goals] & " : " & [away_team_goals] & " " & AwayTeam,
                              ", ")

Return ResultList
```

Unfortunately i get the error **The column 'Clubs[club_name]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.** in the calculate part of the code, and I don't understand this error because my tables are already properly connected via relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a single value from a column in calculate ,  you need to use VALUES() function: unless It is certain that no aggregation is needed here!)

I haven't tested it yet, please let me know If It solves your problem.

```
HighestWin =
VAR BiggestGD = MAXX(Matches, 
                    ABS(Matches[home_team_goals] - Matches[away_team_goals]))
VAR BiggestGDRow = 
    FILTER(Matches, 
        ABS(Matches[home_team_goals] - Matches[away_team_goals]) = BiggestGD)

VAR HomeTeam = CALCULATE(VALUES(Related(Clubs[club_name])),USERELATIONSHIP(Clubs[club_id], Matches[home_team_id]))
VAR AwayTeam = CALCULATE(VALUES(Related(Clubs[club_name])), USERELATIONSHIP(Clubs[club_id], Matches[away_team_id]))
VAR ResultList = CONCATENATEX(BiggestGDRow,
                            HomeTeam  & " " & [home_team_goals] & " : " & [away_team_goals] & " " & AwayTeam,
                              ", ")

Return ResultList
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error

Comment: Thank you for the negative feedback. Is it possible to share some actual data and your full data model If It is not a secret.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECTEDVALUE` instead of `RELATED` within your `CALCULATE` statements.